# finding the max of value for each key in multiple dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have 3 dictionaries and need to create a new dictionary which should contain the highest number of value for the same key. For example r1 has (10, 100), r2 has (10, 200), r3 has (10, 500). The new dictionary should have 10, 500.

```
public Dictionary<Double, Double> r1 = new Dictionary<Double, Double>(); 
public Dictionary<Double, Double> r2 = new Dictionary<Double, Double>(); 
public Dictionary<Double, Double> r3 = new Dictionary<Double, Double>();
```

Comment: What should happen if not all dictionaries have the same set of keys?

Comment: r1 has (10, 100), r2 has (10, 200), r3 has no data on 10. The new dictionary would have 10, 200

Comment: I understand that, but what if r1 has (20, 100), r2 has (20, 200), and r3 doesn't contain the key 20 at all?

Comment: @cdhowie the dictionary should be 20,200

Comment: all dictionaries only have 1 entry? ...i mean r1 will have one entry {10,100} for example ,isthat right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new[] { r1, r2, r3 }.SelectMany(p => p).GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(p => p.Value));
```

Edit:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var r1 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 10, 200 } };
        var r2 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 10, 300 } };
        var r3 = new Dictionary<double, double> { { 10, 500 } };

        var r = Merge(r1, r2, r3);

        foreach (var p in r)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.Key, p.Value);
    }

    static IDictionary<double, double> Merge(params Dictionary<double, double>[] dicts)
    {
        return dicts.SelectMany(p => p).ToLookup(p => p.Key, p => p.Value).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Max());
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnRyann that's all the code there is. Assign it to a variable and you have yourself a dictionary of maximum values of your 3 other dictionaries.

Comment: Exact same idea but more compact than mine. :) +1

Comment: Awesome!! You DA MAN!

Comment: How about if I dont know how many dicrionaries I would have. I could have r1, r2, r3 OR I could have r1-r100. How to do this? Say I have a list of dictionaries, how to loop and implement your code, in this cas. just want to learn from you. thanks

Comment: what about if I dont know there will be 3 dict? it could be 10 dicts this means I can't do var r = Merge(r1, r2, r3);

Comment: @JohnRyann `SelectMany` is a [LINQ](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) method that will accept any `IEnumebrable` of dictionaries, regardless of many many there are or if it's an array, a list or anything else that can be enumerated.

Comment: yes. I know that. But I still need to call Merge. What about if the dictionaries are in a list (ie list of dictionaries)? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
r1.Concat(r2).Concat(r3)
  .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
  .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<double, double>(g.Key, g.Max(p => p.Value)))
  .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p  => p.Value);
```

Not tested but the idea is:

- get all the pairs
- group them by key
- generate a new pair with the max of each group
- convert this set to a dictionary

Comment: This probably would work, but concatenating the three dictionaries means you immediately lose the advantage of being able to look up entries in the lists by key, so the `GroupBy()` is going to be slow.  It may not hurt in this case to specialize the code to take advantage of key lookups.

Comment: I think you make a good point but this is often the price to pay with LINQ. Moreover performance issues should not be anticipated too much. :)

Comment: Of course, premature optimization is evil. But sometimes it pays to anticipate performance issues, such as in this case where you have the items already grouped, flatten them back out, and then regroup them. ;)